# How to dynamically set value of an object property in reactJS state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Let's say a component has state such as:

```
this.state = {
  enabled: {
    one: false,
    two: false,
    three: false
  }
}
```

How can `this.setState()` be used to set the value of a dynamic property?

For instance, this does not work:

```
let dynamicProperty = "one"
this.setState({
  enabled[dynamicProperty]: true
})
```

However, this does work, but is also bad practice:

```
this.enabled = {
  one: false,
  two: false,
  three: false
}
let dynamicProperty = "one"
this.enabled[dynamicProperty] = true;
```

How can `this.setState()` be used to accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a copy of the original object and only change the property you want to update. The easiest way to do that is to use the object spread operator:

```
this.setState(currentState => ({enabled: {...currentState.enabled, one: true}}));
```

or in a more verbose form:

```
this.setState(currentState => {
    const enabled = {...currentState.enabled, one: true};
    return {enabled};
});
```

If the property name is only known at runtime you can do it like this:

```
const setEnabled = name => {
    this.setState(currentState => ({enabled: {...currentState.enabled, [name]: true}}));
};
```

Comment: hmm for some reason this didnt work for me EDIT: the change to [propertyName] worked.

Answer (score 1):

The standard practice is to copy the the state, modify the copied state, then set state using that clone, like this:

```
//with spread operator
const enabledClone = {...this.state.enabled};
enabledClone.one = true;
this.setState({enabled : enabledClone});
```

Comment: this worked for me, however I gave the correct answer to @trxn because 1) answered first 2) part A of his answer was more succinct

Answer (score 1):

You can use braces around an object's key to use a variable to determine the key

```
const dynamicKey = 'one';
const newObj = {[dynamicKey]: true} //equals {one: true}
```

Since this.setState only merges on toplevel keys, you will have to create a copy of the current enabled object and use the braces notation:

```
 let dynamicProperty = "one"
 this.setState({
   enabled: {...this.state.enabled, [dynamicProperty]: true}
 })
```